# How do I turn $\cos(3\theta)$ into a polynomial?

Tags: legendre-polynomials

I am solving some spherical symmetry surface charge stuff. A problem gave me a surface charge of $$\sigma(\theta)=k\cos(3\theta).$$
I was having trouble using this to find the constants of my PDE, so I looked at the solutions... apparently
$$
\cos(3\theta)=4\cos^3(\theta) - 3\cos(\theta)??
$$
Well I did not know that. Why is this true?

For an epilogue, the solution continues:
$$
4\cos^3(\theta) - 3\cos(\theta)=\alpha P_3(\cos(\theta)) + \beta P_1(\cos(\theta)).
$$
..algebra..
$$
\sigma(\theta)=\frac{k}{5}[8P_3(\cos \theta) -3P_1(\cos\theta)].
$$
I am both amazed and terrified at what took place on this page. Never have I seen the $\cos\theta$ go into the legendre polynomial like that. Anyways, I will accept that, but

#### How does $\cos(3\theta)=4\cos^3(\theta) - 3\cos(\theta)?$

Comment: `I am both amazed and terrified at ...` It gets even worse ;-) lookup [Chebyshev's polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#Trigonometric_definition) which express $\,\cos n \theta = T_n(\cos \theta)\,$. Yours is $\,T_3\,$.

Comment: Do you know the addition formula for cosine? $\cos(A+B)=\cos A\cos B-\sin A\sin B$, so $\cos(2A)=\cos^2A-\sin^2A$, then use the identity $\sin^2=1-\cos^2$ to express $\cos(2A)$ in terms of cosines only. Continue that way for $\cos(3A)$.

Comment: @Lubin I really liked that thank you

Answer (score 4):

One way to show it is by using [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula): $e^{i\theta}=\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)$. Then
$$\cos(3\theta)+i\sin(3\theta)=e^{i3\theta}=(\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta))^3.$$
By expanding the cube on the right, and by taking the real part of both sides we get
$$\cos(3\theta)=\cos(\theta)^3-3\cos(\theta)\sin^2(\theta)=\cos(\theta)^3-3\cos(\theta)(1-\cos^2(\theta))\\=4\cos^3(\theta) - 3\cos(\theta).$$

Comment: That's elegant than you. This is the one can be pretty quick.

Answer (score 2):

Another way that works OK for this particular case
$$
\begin{align}
\cos(3\theta) &=\cos(\theta+2\theta)\\
&=\cos(\theta)\cos(2\theta)-\sin(\theta)\sin(2\theta)\\
&=\cos(\theta)(2\cos^2(\theta)-1)-2\sin^2(\theta)\cos(\theta)\\
&=2\cos^3(\theta)-\cos(\theta)-2(1-\cos^2(\theta))\cos(\theta)\\
&=4\cos^3(\theta)-3\cos(\theta)
\end{align}
$$